A relationship between Gamma and Beta distributions
In this paper I found the following fact:
If $V_i \sim \text{Beta}(1, \alpha)$ are i.i.d. for $i = 1, \dots ,n$, then the product $\prod_{i = 1}^n(1 - V_i)$ has the same distribution as $e^{-T}$ where $T \sim \text{Gamma}(n-1, \alpha).$
How does one prove this?

We have $V_i \sim \text{Beta}(1, \alpha)$ then $1 - V_i \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, 1)$ (see here), taking logarithm, we get $-\ln(1 - V_k) \sim \text{Exp}(\alpha)$ (see this question). Therefore,
$$
    -\sum_{k = 1}^n \ln(1 - V_k) \sim \text{Gamma}(n, \alpha)
$$
(see this question) which means,
$$
     \prod_{k = 1}^n (1 - V_k) \sim e^{-T}, \text{ where } T \sim \text{Gamma}(n, \alpha)
$$
